# CORS Origin FAILED Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-services, cors

I need you because @CROSSOrigin doesn't work and i don't understand why, you have my code here. In fact, i use WebService but i have a problem with the 'Acess-Control-Allow-Origin" i tried all but nothing had worked, please help me !!

SPRING BOOT Project with version 2.1.2 and i would like to build a REST API for ANGULAR 7

PROBLEM:

```js
zone.js:3243 GET http://localhost:8080/apiEquipment/equipments 404
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/apiEquipment/equipments' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
zone.js:3243 XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/apiEquipment/equipments".
core.js:15714 ERROR 
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:8080/apiEquipment/equipments", ok: false, …}
```

pom.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
 <groupId>com.example</groupId>
 <artifactId>GoSecuriServices</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>GoSecuriServices</name>
 <description>Rest API for GoSecuri Application</description>

 <properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

Application.java

```js
package com.example.GoSecuriServices;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.GoSecuriServices.repository") 
@EntityScan("com.example.GoSecuriServices.model")
@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class GoSecuriServicesApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(GoSecuriServicesApplication.class, args);
 }
 
}
```

Equipment.java (my table)

```js
package model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Equipment")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Equipment {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Equipment_id;

    @NotBlank
    private String EquipmentName;

    @NotBlank
    private Integer Nb;


    // Getters and Setters
    public Long getEquipment_id() {
     return this.Equipment_id;
    }
    
    public void SetEquipment_id(Long id) {
     this.Equipment_id = id;
    }
    
    
    public String getEquipmentName() {
     return this.EquipmentName;
    }
    
    public void setEquipmentName(String name) {
     this.EquipmentName = name;
    }
    
    
    public Integer getNb() {
     return this.Nb;
    }
    
    public void setNb(Integer nb) {
     this.Nb = nb;
    }
    
}
```

EquipmentRepository.java

```js
package repository;

import model.Equipment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface EquipmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Equipment, Long> {

}
```

EquipmentController.java

```js
package controller;

import exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import model.Equipment;
import repository.EquipmentRepository;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;


@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/apiEquipment")
public class EquipmentController {
 
 @Autowired
    EquipmentRepository equipmentRepository;
 
 @RequestMapping(value= "/apiEquipment/**", method=RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
 public void corsHeaders(HttpServletResponse response) {
     response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
     response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, x-requested-with");
     response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
 }
 
 // Get all equipments
 @GetMapping("/equipments")
 public List<Equipment> getAllEquipments() {
  return equipmentRepository.findAll();
 }
 
 
 // Create new equipment
 @PostMapping("/equipments")
 public Equipment createEquipment(@Valid @RequestBody Equipment equipment) {
  return equipmentRepository.save(equipment);
 }
 
 // Get a single equipment
 @GetMapping("/equipments/{id}")
 public Equipment getEquipmentById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long equipmentId) {
  return equipmentRepository.findById(equipmentId)
   .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Equipment", "id", equipmentId));
 }
 
 // Update a Equipment
 @PutMapping("/equipments/{id}")
 public Equipment updateNote(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long equipmentId,
                                         @Valid @RequestBody Equipment equipmentDetails) {

     Equipment equipment = equipmentRepository.findById(equipmentId)
             .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Equipment", "id", equipmentId));

     equipment.setEquipmentName(equipmentDetails.getEquipmentName());
     equipment.setNb(equipmentDetails.getNb());

     Equipment updatedEquipment = equipmentRepository.save(equipment);
     return updatedEquipment;
 }
 
 // Delete a Equipment
 @DeleteMapping("/equipments/{id}")
 public ResponseEntity<?> deleteEquipment(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long equipmentId) {
  Equipment equipment = equipmentRepository.findById(equipmentId)
    .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Equipment", "id", equipmentId));
  
  equipmentRepository.delete(equipment);
  
  return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
 }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Did you read the CORS Support section in Spring Documentation?](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html#_global_cors_configuration)

You can also try to use [Spring Higher-Order Components and @EnableCORS](https://github.com/jpomykala/spring-higher-order-components#enablecors) or if you don't want to use additional dependency use `@Bean` from [here](https://github.com/jpomykala/spring-higher-order-components/blob/master/src/main/java/me/jpomykala/starters/springhoc/cors/SpringHocCORSAutoConfiguration.java)

Comment: Did you try to use the second solution?

Comment: Yes, I've tried Bean and the other way to enable CORS i don't understand why didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a web cross-domain configuration as follows:

```
package com.liukai.routermanagement.config;

import com.liukai.routermanagement.interceptor.LoginHandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport;

@SpringBootConfiguration
public class MyWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(new LoginHandlerInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("/user/login","/router/login","/user/registered");
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
    }

// this main mothod，Just add this method
    @Override
    protected void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowCredentials(true).allowedMethods("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE");
        super.addCorsMappings(registry);
    }
}
```